# USA Green Card holder

Tags: usa, international-travel, us-residents

I am a Green Card holder (CR1) who is a spouse of an American citizen. My Green Card will expire in March 2020 and I am planning to travel abroad from the USA in December and when I come back it will be in January, so is it okay to travel?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be ok to travel?

Comment: Note that If you intend on renewing your GC, you can start the renewal process 6 months before the expiry date. Part of that process is a physical interview where the validity of your current GC is extended in order to account for the additional time that the new GC will take to arrive.

Comment: For my case I have to renewal it in the last three months 90 days I was afraid if in this period I wasn't in USA something will happen

Comment: @PeterM CR-1 is the two-year conditional status.

Answer (score 4):

You are OK to travel, if you come back in January 2020 since your Green Card will expire in March of 2020 provided you have a valid travel document (passport or  refugee travel document).

I assume your intention is to become a US citizen and therefore please note the following from [FindLaw: Immigration](https://immigration.findlaw.com/visas/can-a-person-with-a-green-card-travel-outside-the-united-states.html)

> ..to become a naturalized citizen ... you must have been physically present in the U.S. for at least 30 months out of the previous five years to establish continuous residency

Comment: It is not necessary for a green card holder to present a passport or any other document in addition to the green card in order to enter the US.  The valid passport or other travel document is likely to be needed to enter the destination country, but it will not be necessary if the destination country is Canada and the mode of transportation is other than air.

Comment: Note that the continuous residence requirement is separate from the physical presence requirement. For naturalization under the 5-year rule, the person needs to have been continuously resident for the last 5 years, *and* physically present for 30 months of the last 5 years. (Or for naturalization under the 3-year rule, the person needs to have bee continuously resident for the last 3 years, and physically present for 18 months of the last 3 years.)